# Find matrix that implements Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\0&4&5\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$$

I have calculated the eigenvectors: $$\{\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{3}\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{8}{5}\\-\frac{5}{2}\\-1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

However, I am trying to find the matrix $S$ such that $$SBS^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$$

(The jordan normal form)

I have been told that the columns of $S$ are the eigenvectors of $B$, but $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{8}{5} \\
 0 & -1 & -\frac{5}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 0 & 4 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{15} \\
 0 & -1 & \frac{5}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & \frac{13}{3} \\
 0 & 4 & 10 \\
 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Do I need scalar multiples of the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the eigenvectors gives a matrix such that
$$B=SJS^{-1}\ ,$$
in other words
$$J=S^{-1}BS\ .$$
So you have used $S$ where you should have used $S^{-1}$, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh lord! You just saved me a pile of time. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you think carefully it is obvious that it must be this way round.  Because finding $BS$ involves multiplying $B$ by columns of $S$, in other words $B$ times eigenvectors, which is the whole point of eigenvectors.  But $SB$ means nothing in particular.

Comment: Would multiples of the eigenvectors still result in the Jordan form?

Comment: A (non-zero) multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector, so yes.  In the case where the same eigenvalue occurs more than once, you have to be a bit careful.